# How to get the count of records comparing days between two dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @UserId varchar(30);
declare @StartDate datetime;
declare @EndDate datetime;

set @UserId = 'E2';
set @StartDate = '2016-12-01';
set @EndDate = '2016-12-14';

select 
    COUNT((dueDate < finishDate) or finishDate = nul) as exceedTasks,   
    COUNT(taskID) as totalTasks 
from 
    Task
where 
    empId = @UserId 
    and startDate >= @StartDate 
    and dueDate <= @EndDate
```

I want get the `count` of tasks which are exceed `dueDate`.But this query has syntax error.

Comment: could you add the error you get?

Comment: SQL-Server or MySQL or Oracle or ...?

Comment: SQL-Server." Error-Incorrect syntax near ')'.  "(COUNT((dueDate<finishDate) or finishDate=nul))**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this because you have written nul instead of null.
You can try this

```
declare @UserId varchar(30);
declare @StartDate datetime;
declare @EndDate datetime;

set @UserId = 'E2';
 set @StartDate = '2016-12-01';
   set @EndDate = '2016-12-14';

  select 
 COUNT((dueDate < finishDate) or finishDate = null) as exceedTasks,   
     COUNT(taskID) as totalTasks 
   from 
    Task
      where 
empId = @UserId 
and startDate >= @StartDate 
and dueDate <= @EndDate
```

Try This

```
 declare @UserId varchar(30);
declare @StartDate datetime;
 declare @EndDate datetime;

set @UserId = 'E2';
set @StartDate = '2016-12-01';
 set @EndDate = '2016-12-14';

 select 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN dueDate < finishDate THEN dueDate WHEN finishDate = null THEN dueDate END ) as exceedTasks,   
 COUNT(taskID) as totalTasks 
   from 
   Task
  where 
empId = @UserId 
and startDate >= @StartDate 
and dueDate <= @EndDate
```

Comment: No Its 0 Voted Go to Up and Down Symbol and Press Up Symbol for upvote like I upvoted yor question

Comment: when I vote it.This message is coming "Thanks for the feedback!. Votes cast by those less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"